# iOS app crashes when opened by url/ during fitbit authorization

Tags: ios, url, fitbit

I am trying to implement fitbit authorization in my iOS app. Specifically, I am trying to follow the steps in the [get authorization from Fitbit using Oauth in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36915238/get-authorization-from-fitbit-using-oauth-in-ios/37589936#37589936?newreg=a31ae97a6ebc4776817c58de69c3638c). Currently, I have followed point 1 and my app redirects to safari to login to the fitbit account, then transitions back to my app, which immediately crashes.

I have set up a URL scheme to be the name of my app, and my callback URL/ redirect URI are both set to myAppName://. I have also implemented a func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {} method in my AppDelegate which is never being called.

Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

More generally: why an app would be crashing when opened by a url.

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling Fitbit authentication once the user enters his credential fitbit will call your callback url. so 
you need to handle that call back in your app delegate like this.

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation {

  NSString *strUrl =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url];
  if ([strUrl containsString:@"#_=_"]) {
    [self saveFitbitCode:url];
    return YES;
  }
}
```

Now in saveFitbitCode method I am retrieving auth_code and then sending local notification so it will call another functional for access token.

```
-(void)saveFitbitCode:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSString *strUrl =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url];
    NSRange range1 = [strUrl rangeOfString:@"code="];
    NSRange range2 = [strUrl rangeOfString:@"#_=_"];


    NSRange rSub = NSMakeRange(range1.location + range1.length, range2.location - range1.location - range1.length);
    NSString *sub = [strUrl substringWithRange:rSub];

   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:sub forKey:@"auth_code"];
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"callRequest" object:nil userInfo:nil];
}
```

I hope this will help you.